# Android: Save file on accessible path

Tags: android, file, path, storage

I need to write a file in a path accessible for the user, for example in a folder named 'documents' in the internal memory. Above is the code which I'm using, but I don't know how to insert the path.

How can I save the file in this path?

Thank's

```
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("xData.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

    outputStreamWriter.append(strXStorage);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    strException = e.toString();
}
```

Comment: The MODE_PRIVATE means that only you application will be able to read files. You want to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory to get the user-accessible storage

Comment: ...which these days is usually internal to the phone.  And don't forget to invoke the media scanner.